# Is this inequality valid?

Tags: inequality

$p_i  \  \ \ , \ \ q_i \  \ \ > 0 $    and  $x_i \ge y_i $ for $ \ \  i  \in {1,2, \dots ,n}$ . We also have that $\sum_{1}^{n} (p_i - q_i ) = 0 $ . Then , is it true that $\sum_{1}^{n} (p_i x_i - q_iy_i) \ge 0 $  ?

Comment: Take $p_1=p, p_2=0, q_1=0, q_2=p$ and $x_1=1=y_1, x_2=2=y_2$.

Comment: Please see edited problem < @SeverinSchraven .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $(2-1)+(1-2)=0$, but $(2\times 3-1\times 3)+(1\times 4-2\times 4)<0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, let $p_{1}=1,p_{2}=2,q_{1}=2,q_{2}=1$ and let $x_{1}=y_{1}=4$ and $x_{2}=y_{2}=1$, then
$$\sum^{2}_{i=1}p_{i}-q_{i}=0,\text{ but }\sum^{2}_{i=1}x_{i}p_{i}-q_{i}y_{i}=-3.$$

Comment: $\sum p_i - q_i$ has to be $0$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, Thank you you're right, I misread the question. I've fixed my answer. Same principle applies though.